# Incorrect filename and funcName when importing a module with a class for logging

Tags: python, logging

I want to use a decorator for logging and created a special Loggerator class for this. However, when I import this class into another file, when logging, filename and funcName are specified from the Loggerator.py file.
I want to get these attributes from the file where I am using the decorator. How can I do it?

```
#Loggerator.py
import logging


class Loggerator:

    def __init__(self, func):
        logging.basicConfig(
            filename='example3.log',
            format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d | %(levelname)-8s | %(name)s | %(filename)s.%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) | %(message)s',
            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            level=logging.DEBUG,
            encoding='utf-8')
        self.func = func
        self.log = logging.getLogger(func.__name__)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.log.debug(f'call {self.func.__name__}')
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as err:
            self.log.exception(err)
            return err
        finally:
            self.log.debug(f'end of {self.func.__name__}')
```

Second file.

```
#test.py
from Loggerator import Loggerator

@Loggerator
def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

print(mult(3, 2))
print(mult('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: Note that the reason for this is, that you usually issue a logging call directly inside the function, instead of through a decorator. `funcName` and `filename` refer to where the logging call is issued, which in the standard case, would be `mult` and `test.py`. Going through the decorator, these obviously now take the name of your decorator class `__call__` method.

Comment: I don't know if it is solution for this or not. But you can use wrapper to send parameters to the needed function from decorator.